# 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I am getting the following error. How can I solve this problem?

> 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.